# Rails uploading a specific file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload

I have an Attachment model, and it keeps a file. I m using paperclip, that's why I keep it like

```
t.attachment :file
```

I want to upload a file in a specific path like

```
:rails_root/non-public/sample.txt
```

How can I upload this file without using a form. Is there any way to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible if you don't want it to go through a `<form>` as that's the only way to ask user for a file.

Comment: did you pay attention to files path?, it is in rails project

Comment: I want to create new attachment in a method

Comment: @RamazanZor upload file via Ajax